# How do I load database credentials from a properties file in JPA?

Tags: java, properties, persistence, jpa-2.0

So I have a Java/JPA2.0 (EclipseLink) app that connects to a MySQL database.  My intention is just passing a JAR file around with a `db.properties` file.  The `db.properties` should contain the server host address, username, password, etc so that the end user can just plug that in and start using the JAR in their projects.

Currently, I just used Netbeans to create a `persistence.xml` file with the credentials and that works.  But how do I implement the properties file?

My EntityManager class:

```
public class Factories {

    private static final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = buildEntityManagerFactory();

        private static EntityManagerFactory buildEntityManagerFactory() {
            try {
                return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPU");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the two-parameter version of the [`createEntityManagerFactory()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#createEntityManagerFactory%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29) method. The second argument (the Map) can be used to pass properties including the credentials to the database. You can therefore pass in a map with keys `javax.persistence.jdbc.user` and `javax.persistence.jdbc.password` and appropriate values.

An [example in the EclipseLink wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/OutsideContainer) demonstrates how to achieve this, although it uses classes provided by EclipseLink to achieve this:

```
import static org.eclipse.persistence.config.PersistenceUnitProperties.*;

    ...

    Map properties = new HashMap();

    // Ensure RESOURCE_LOCAL transactions is used.
    properties.put(TRANSACTION_TYPE,
        PersistenceUnitTransactionType.RESOURCE_LOCAL.name());

    // Configure the internal EclipseLink connection pool
    properties.put(JDBC_DRIVER, "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    properties.put(JDBC_URL, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL");
    properties.put(JDBC_USER, "scott");
    properties.put(JDBC_PASSWORD, "tiger");

    // Configure logging. FINE ensures all SQL is shown
    properties.put(LOGGING_LEVEL, "FINE");
    properties.put(LOGGING_TIMESTAMP, "false");
    properties.put(LOGGING_THREAD, "false");
    properties.put(LOGGING_SESSION, "false");

    // Ensure that no server-platform is configured
    properties.put(TARGET_SERVER, TargetServer.None);

    // Now the EntityManagerFactory can be instantiated for testing using: 
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(unitName, properties);
```

Note that, it is also possible to do this via the [`EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html#createEntityManager%28java.util.Map%29) method, which accepts properties. However, if you read the [EclipseLink auditing example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Auditing) carefully, you'll notice that a shared connection pool (whose properties are derived from persistence.xml) is also created, and that actual connection in use would depend on whether you are performing reads or writes.